# How to store and use multiple cart_ids in a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm hoping anyone can point me in the right direction as I've been breaking my head around this issue for a couple of days .

A single website lists multiple shops, each with a show page, from which a user can select and add products to a (session) cart. Every shop has a corresponding cart. The user performs an individual checkout process for each cart. On the carts#index page, the user can see an overview of the active carts.

I've found the below snippet to be completely working. Yet, when trying to upgrade the set_cart method to include multiple carts, my own logic and ideas fail.

```rb
module CurrentCart
  private

  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

An approach that worked, but isn't very scalable, is to create 1 session cart for the entire website and then send a shop instance to filter down (i.e., @cart.items_for_shop(@shop). The issue is that both a cart instance and a shop instance need to be available everywhere in the app. It would make much more sense to have a separate cart_id for each shop.

How would you approach storing multiple carts in the session?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go down the route of having a ParentCart, or MetaCart, or whatever you want to call the thing that all the carts for each shop belong to. Lets go with `UberCart` for this example.

So, your `set_cart` method finds or creates an `UberCart` record, exactly as you currently have for a normal `Cart`.

Next, for each shop, either when you create the `UberCart`, or maybe later when you view a shop ... up to you, you create a `Cart`, which is essentially a join table between your `UberCart` and the chosen `Shop`.

`LineItem`s from the `Shop` are then attached to the correct `Cart`, which is accessible from the `UberCart` in your session.

In your `CartController#index` action you can then just use `@uber_cart.carts` to access all the carts belonging to this `UberCart`.

Comment: Great, that worked. Amazing how it simplifies the app. Thanks a lot!!